# Change nameserver in DNS to different hosting

Tags: dns, nameservers

I am going to change my hosting, and allready rented a new server. 
Now I want to configure my DNS via the new hosting/server but my domain is still registrered at the 'old' hoster, how should I do this correctly?

I have tried it via the following two ways, both not working:

1. Setting up DNS at 'old' host, with my new ip-address at my DNS-records in stead of the old IP. I get `Apache is functioning normally`... while everything is configured correctly (tested etc, all ok)
2. Changing nameserver at old host to new one, ns1.newhost.com etc, and then configuring the DNS via DirectAdmin on my new VPS... I've done this about 10hrs ago, only now my domain cannot be resolved. If i lookup the NS info via [www.mxtoolbox.com](http://www.mxtoolbox.com/) the new nameservers are shown for the domain, but my DNS config is not working...

Am I missing some settings or DNS records?

Comment: solved by a simple restart & option 1). D'oh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step one: make sure you have a record pointing to your new server. Generally, one would use an A record to achieve this. Then, configure apache to listen for your domainname. You can do this by using the ServerName directive. There's no rule saying the DNS server should be on the same server as the webserver.

Comment: that's the strange thing, had both of these settings done (at my 1st way) and it gave Apache func norm...

Comment: "Apache functioning normally" is a message you get when it's not configured to display anything else. Have you restarted Apache yet, because that's necessary for Apache to take in configuration changes.

Comment: @Bokw Happens to the best of us ;)